# Pyautogui keyboard commands do not work with Menu bar assignments

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am putting together a script to automate certain administrative tasks within SAP GUI. I can click to navigate, use tab, enter strings, and press enter within forms.

Issue: The Menu key assignments don't seem to work when I send them with pyautogui (ex: pyautogui.press('F12') ). This forces me to have to use other alternatives (buggy mouse clicks and what not). Any idea why these don't work?

I can work without - but I'd like to know if anyone understands what exactly is happening... It would be great if I could!

Answer (score 0):

pyautogui.press is case-sensitive, or at least it is on Windows. So you need to say

```
pyautogui.press('f12')
```

Here's a [list of the keys](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys).

It might be handy to define this stub

```
show_trivial_nags = True #maybe be able to toggle this on the command line

def ci_press(x):
    if x != x.lower() and show_trivial_nags:
        print("WARNING: press commands should be in lower case.")
    pyautogui.press(x.lower())
```

The test case I used was, with Firefox next in alt-tab,

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
# Comment out the first, and the search bar still appears. Comment out the second, and it doesn't.
pyautogui.press('F3')
pyautogui.press('f3')
exit()
```